# Изменение разрядности аудиоданных с 16 bit на 8 bit

Tags: c#, uwp, аудио

Я хочу изменить разрядность с 16 бит на 8 бит. 
Вот код конвертации с 32 bit на 16 bit:

```
var audioBuffer = frame.LockBuffer(AudioBufferAccessMode.Read);
var buffer = Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer.CreateCopyFromMemoryBuffer(audioBuffer);
buffer.Length = audioBuffer.Length;

using (var dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer))
{
    dataReader.ByteOrder = ByteOrder.LittleEndian;
    byte[] byteData = new byte[buffer.Length / (4 * 3)];
    int pos = 0;
    Int16 int16Tmp1;
    Int16 int16Tmp2;
    Int16 avg = 0;
    while (dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            int16Tmp1 = (Int16)((dataReader.ReadSingle() * Int16.MaxValue) / 2);
            int16Tmp2 = (Int16)((dataReader.ReadSingle() * Int16.MaxValue) / 2);
            avg += (Int16)(int16Tmp1 + int16Tmp2);
        }

        avg = (Int16)(avg / 3);
        byte[] chunkBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(avg);
        byteData[pos++] = chunkBytes[0];
        byteData[pos++] = chunkBytes[1];
    }

    _audioStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
}
```

Вот попытка конвертации с 32 bit на 8 bit:

```
                dataReader.ByteOrder = ByteOrder.LittleEndian;
                byte[] byteData = new byte[buffer.Length / (4 * 3 * 2)];
                int pos = 0;
                sbyte int8Tmp1;
                sbyte int8Tmp2;
                sbyte avg = 0;
                while (dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        int8Tmp1 = (sbyte)((dataReader.ReadSingle() * sbyte.MaxValue) / 2);
                        int8Tmp2 = (sbyte)((dataReader.ReadSingle() * sbyte.MaxValue) / 2);
                        avg += (sbyte)(int8Tmp1 + int8Tmp2);
                    }
                    avg = (sbyte)(avg / 3);
                    byte[] chunkBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(avg);
                    byteData[pos++] = (byte)(avg);
                    //byteData[pos++] = chunkBytes[0];
                    //byteData[pos++] = chunkBytes[1];
                }
```

`DataReader` читает аудиофрейм:

1. стерео.
2. 32 bit
3. 48 kHz.

Я это преобразую в моно с 16 разрядностью и 16 kHz. Ну, я по крайней мере надеюсь, что это правильно.

Так вот, что мне нужно изменить, что бы получать 8 битный звук?

Comment: Теоретически если вам с двух байт нужно оставить один, то закоментировав строку  byteData[pos++] = chunkBytes[0];  - получится относительно правильный результат, но меня ещё смущает dataReader.ReadSingle().

Comment: @nick_n_a Там массив float-ов, поэтому и ReadSingle().  Делал вот по этому: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs]


И там написано: **Поддерживаются только 32-разрядные форматы с плавающей точкой**.

Comment: Плюс, как мне кажется, ваш вариант не работает. Я закомментировал то, что вы сказали. И на выходе получается лишь шум.

Comment: стандартный wave riff поддерживает целый тип (знаковый byte). Если вы хотите изменить разрядность, то явно байт должно получится в 2 раза меньше. А зачем вам 8 битный звук? Какой метод его будет воспроизводить? Я обрабатывал звук wave, но на входе у меня были int16 для 16-битного звука, и int8 для 8-битного. 8-битное float я в студии не нашёл.

Comment: @nick_n_a 8-битное уже не float, как и 16 битное. В 16 битном у меня short-ы. 
Понятно, что байт должно быть в два раза меньше, но при записывании лишь одного из chunkBytes[] (естественно, я уменьшил длину byteData), я в итоге получаю лишь помехи. Никакого нормального звука.

Пока что я не воспроизвожу этот звук в моем приложении, а лишь накапливаю и сохраняю как .wav.

Comment: Плюс ещё я сменил Int16 на sbyte.

Comment: Так, давайте ещёраз, если 16bit у вас работает, то ваша ошибка 1)в том, что вы делите на 3, а не на 256 (что б разделить на 256 надо взять вторые 8 бит, т..е. chunkBytes[1] или таки делить на 256 вместо 3 и брать [0]). 2) вместо byteData.Length написать pos.

Comment: @nick_n_a Я добавил в вопрос код, в котором я пытаюсь конвертировать 32 битное на 8 битное. Я забыл написать, что выложенный мною код конвертирует на 16 битный.